# query mysql database before insertion of records from xml file via php

Tags: php, mysql

If my database contains some
previous records, how can I query each db row before new record can be inserted into database from my xml file (containing 400 records) to 
prevent duplicated insertions for
every xml file load or read
sessions.
 Below is the Php & mysql code that simply read and upload the whole records.

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("d:\salarydepartment
\salary.xml");
    $status=count($xml);
foreach ( $xml as $sal)
    {
    $name=$sal->name;
    $sex=$sal->sex;
    $state=$sal->state;
    $country=$sal->country;
    $result=mysql_query
("insert into salary
(name,sex,state,country ) values
($name,$sex,$state,$country)",$con)
    echo $status." "." Salary Records
successfully stored ! ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Dont use mysql_* functions any more.They are deprecated.Use mysqli_*...

Comment: Maybe you want to use a UNIQUE index on one more more columns, and use INSERT IGNORE …?

Comment: What is(are) the primary key(s) of your salary table ? You just have to make a SELECT statement before your insert in order to check if there is already a corresponding record.

Comment: You can use select query with where conditions before insert

Comment: Deepu, Cbroe, kewlashu & OlivierH
how can all dat b done ? please provide detail sample.

Answer (score 0):

## Changing your table scheme

### Adding Unique constraint

this is your insert query:

```
INSERT INTO salary (name,sex,state,country) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

I will assume your table has the following schema

```
salary (name, sex, state, country)
```

You don't want records to be duplicated. Therefore you must have some method of checking wether a record is already inserted or not, which means one (or a combination of) column must be unique. My guess is that your xml files do not contain any `unique identifiers` per `employee`.

We should then consider adding a constraint to the table that gathers enough info so that the number of collisions is low.

```
ALTER TABLE salary ADD UNIQUE KEY (name,sex,state,country)
//This sql statement is intended for MySQL version 5.1 please check your's
```

With this constraint, the only duplicates allowed are people in the same country and state, of the same sex and with the same name.

### Adding a Primary key

Now, this will not be a good solution so I propose a better one on the following assumption

- employees have a unique ID and that it can be found in the xml

Ok, now it's very simple, but tedious

- we need to add a column to the table `ALTER TABLE salary ADD COLUMN...`
- we need to populate **all** tuples with the unique ID of each employee
- we finally add the **important** constraint `ALTER TABLE salary ADD PRIMARY KEY...`

The table is now optimized for quick searches